# How do I can change the default django rest_auth redirection?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-packages

hi I'm using django rest_auth package for managing my project's authentication system. when I do register or log in with a user it gives me just a key and doesn't redirect user to any page and for logout as well.
how do I can redirect users to my home page after login, logout and register???

Comment: It sounds like you are working with a REST api? If that is the case everything will be handled in the client that is calling the api and not the server itself. You did not give enough information about your project to answer your question.

Comment: yes I'm working with a rest api. what information you want to know??

Comment: I just creating the api and my colleague create the User Interface you mean the redirection would be in the user side and java script??

Comment: Yes, typically the front-end will send a request asking to log in or log out, then the server will send a response saying whether or not the action was successful. The front-end will then determine based on that response whether or not the user should be redirected.

Comment: thank you for your help.